# How can I find out the make and model of the chips in my device?

Tags: bluetooth, gps, hardware

I'm trying to find out what kind of GPS receiver is in my phone. Every spec sheet is vague on this. I can easily find out what kind Soc or CPU it has, but parts like GPS and FM receivers, Bluetooth modules, Gyroscope etc. are not listed anywhere.

Is there **any** way to find it out?

Comment: What general phone model is it to begin with?

Comment: @ce4 Well the more general the solution, the better but the device that I'm most interested in is a Droid Charge.

Comment: Some hint may also stay in the obligatory android kernel source and may also be accessible via the commandline (dmesg and such)

Answer (score 10):

For the best resource out there, use [PDADB](http://pdadb.net/).

This details every comprehensive chip-set used, for the [Droid Charge](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2737&view=1&c=samsung_sch-i510_droid_charge_4g_lte_samsung_stealth), this is the spec sheet given.

As for [Huawei U8160](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2874&view=1&c=vodafone_858_smart_huawei_u8160), this is the spec sheet given on that page.

Depending on how open the manufacturer is with the more intimate details, some may be marked proprietary which will be stated clearly.

The other way of doing it, in the case of the Droid Charge which is a Samsung model, might be to hit up on the Samsung's [open source site](http://opensource.samsung.com), and look for the appropriate kernel version for that handset and examine the kernel configuration as appropriate.

Comment: +1 pdadb is nice, but it doesn't list the Bluetooth chip :( Kernel source might reveal it, but it's a little ridiculous that we need to look at that for such simple stuff.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik ridiculous I know but what other way can you dig it up - *use the source luke!* :) The kernel can reveal a lot more then just any web-site!

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Cheers for the bounty award :)

Answer (score 8):

## http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/

A good starting point. They usually note also the chip/part numbers in their teardown reports.

Comment: I couldn't find my Huawei u8160

Comment: +1 It's a great resource. Sadly it doesn't have a teardown for the Droid Charge.

Comment: There is a pretty good teardown of the Droid Charge on [Droidforums.net](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-general-discussions/146649-samsung-i510-droid-charge-disassembly.html)