# Is there any android smartphone using Atheros chipset?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out the make and model of the chips in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29223/how-can-i-find-out-the-make-and-model-of-the-chips-in-my-device)

I'm now working on a research topic about Hotspot 2.0. However, it's really difficult to find an Android smartphone or tablet using the Atheros chipset.

Does anybody know what Android product is using the Atheros chipset?

Comment: Zte Blade uses ar6003 chipset for wifi.. having said that, [pdadb.net](http://pdadb.net) is your friend to filter out devices that have the specific atheros chipsets.

Comment: Related: [How can I find out the make and model of the chips in my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29223/how-can-i-find-out-the-make-and-model-of-the-chips-in-my-device)

Comment: We don't support individual "searching for X in a device" questions, whether shopping-oriented or just lists (see the [FAQ]).  The question Richard linked is a good option though.

Answer (score -1):

See [Sony Ericsson Xperia X10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Ericsson_Xperia_X10).

Comment: That's true. However, it uses MSM chipset. What about ar600X series? Is there any android smart phone using ar600X chipset?